# How do i turn off the button "glowing" on python tkinter (Linux)?

Tags: python, image, user-interface, tkinter, button

So, i've been learning a bit of tkinter and i've just found out that some things like buttons work differently from windows to linux... On windows everything works fine but on linux, when i over the button (with an image) it glows and, honestly, i can't figure out how to fix this.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
import PySimpleGUI as sg

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Test")
root.geometry("500x500")    

close_icon = PhotoImage(file='assets/Close Button.png')
close_button = tk.Button(root, image=close_icon, command=root.destroy, borderwidth=0)
close_button.pack()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root.mainloop()
```

**What it should always look like:**

[image: What it should always look like]

**What it looks like when i hover it:**

[image: What it looks like when i hover it]

Comment: You may want to put the alt-text back into the question now that I've added images

Answer (score 1):

Try to set option `activebackground` to be the same background color of the window.

```py
color = root.cget("background")
close_button.configure(activebackground=color)
```

Comment: I tried it and it works, thanks! But what if i want to make the background really transparent?

Comment: You can find the answer on stackoverflow if it is about transparent background for the window.